# Google Spreadsheets QUERY() to combine multiple sheets, same workbook

Tags: google-analytics, google-sheets, google-query-language

**Goal:** I'm using QUERY() in gSheets to combine data from multiple sheets in the same workbook. The data is an extract from GA broken down into small segments to prevent sampling. This means it has all the same fields, I'm just piecing it back together for analysis.

I would like to use QUERY() to do this because the data is hooked up to auto-update using the Google Analytics Sheets addon. The idea is that when it updates in the future it will piece itself together again and the analysis will run without any additional effort (or risk of human error) on our part.

I followed the Google Support [syntax](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en), with one accomodation to fit the multiple sheets. This was mentioned on other posts and seems to work for other people--when combined with IMPORTRANGE referencing outside workbooks, though. There has to be a similar way to do it within the same workbook.

**What I've tried:**

```
=QUERY({'LandingPages-Oct1'!A16:F,'LandingPages-Oct2'!A16:F},"select *",0)
```

^ All comma separation causes the sheets to import side by side

```
=QUERY({'LandingPages-Oct1'!A16:F;'LandingPages-Oct2'!A16:F},"select *",0)
```

^ Semicolon separating sheets causes the first sheet of data to appear, but not the second

```
=QUERY({'LandingPages-Oct1'!A16:F;'LandingPages-Oct2'!A16:F};"select *",0)
```

^ Semicolon separating query parameters returns no results

What am I missing?

**Sample data:** https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1STuBdXPCY-mtJdmKZVblR8WlvLaRPa3tl4Kme10sQBQ/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Semicolon separating sheets causes the first sheet of data to appear, but not the second

This usually means you didn't scroll to the bottom of the sheet to see the second part of data there, under all of the empty rows from the first sheet.

Since you probably don't want to import the empty rows, filter them out (by some column that is expected to be nonempty):

```
={filter('LandingPages-Oct1'!A16:F, len('LandingPages-Oct1'!A16:A));
  filter('LandingPages-Oct2'!A16:F, len(LandingPages-Oct2'!A16:A))}
```

No need for query at all; query string `"select *"` means you are not really querying.

Comment: Thank you! You're right, it was the empty rows all along!

Comment: I've tried so many solutions. This one is the only one I've been able to run correctly.

Answer (score 20):

Alternatively, you can also use query to remove the empty rows

```
=QUERY({'LandingPages-Oct1'!A16:F; 'LandingPages-Oct2'!A16:F}, "where Col1 <>''")
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I ended up doing, since I opted to use QUERY() over FILTER(). It works. :)

Answer (score 0):

In regards to:

> ^ Semicolon separating sheets causes the first sheet of data to appear, but not the second

Reason for me why this did not work initially, was that the format of the two tables were not the same. After pasting the same format this worked again.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out to how sort by column using the formula above:

```
=SORT(QUERY({'LandingPages-Oct1'!A16:F; 'LandingPages-Oct2'!A16:F}, "where Col1 <>''"),1,TRUE)
```

This will sort by column 1.

Comment: Sorting can also be done inside the query:  "where Col1 <>'' order by Col1 asc".